# What is the least amount of punctuation required in the following:

Tags: punctuation, quotations

> He told them to stop their whining.

Is there a way to write the above correctly without using quotation marks?

Comment: Quotation marks are only needed if you are trying to convey that "they" said something verbatim (i.e. the words are a direct quote). In order to convey that he merely told them to stop whining, no quotes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I see no need for quotation marks, except if you have some special requirements you haven't told us about.

Simpler:

*He told them **to stop whining**.*

"Their" isn't normally required, except if you have a cacophony of such sounds from multiple sources, all going on at the same time :-)